# How to pass a wrapped component into React Router without it constantly remounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

We're in the process of upgrading our React App, and after many of hours of pain have realised that passing wrapped components into React Router (V4 and maybe others) causes the component to "remount" every time a new prop is passed in.

Here's the wrapped component...

```
export default function preload(WrappedComponent, props) {
    class Preload extends React.Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            getDataForComponent(props);
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
        }
    }
    return Preload;
}
```

And here's how we're using it...

```
const FlagsApp = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route path="/report/:reportId/flag/:id/edit" component{preload(FlagForm, props)} />
    );
};
```

Anytime we're dispatching an action and then receiving a update, the component remounts, causing lots of problems. According to [this thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4630) on github, components will remount if:

> - you call withRouter(..) during rendering which would create a new component class each time
> - you pass a new function to Route.component each render, e.g. using anonymous function 
>     {...}} />, which would create a new component as well

If I pass the `FlagForm` component in directly the problem is fixed, but then I can't take advantage of the `preload` function.

So, how can I achieve the same outcome, but without the component remounting?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit how preload should work? Should it call for the data only once with the very first props it receives? Or should it react to prop changes as well? Where do the props, needed for preload, come from?

Answer (score 1):

The reason `Route` is mounting a new component on every update is that it's been assigned a new class each time via `preload`.

Indeed, each call to `preload` always returns a ***distinct*** *anonymous class*, even 
 when called with the same arguments:

```
console.log( preload(FlagForm,props) != preload(FlagForm,props) ) // true
```

So, since the issue is that `preload` being called within the `FlagsApp` component's `render` method, start by moving it outside of that scope:

```
const PreloadedFlagForm = preload(FlagForm, props) //moved out

const FlagsApp = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route path="/report/:reportId/flag/:id/edit"
            component={PreloadedFlagForm} /> //assign component directly
    );
};
```

This way the component for `Route` won't change between updates.

Now about that lingering `props` argument for `preload`: this is actually an anti-pattern. The proper way to pass in `props` just the standard way you would for any component:

```js
const PreloadedFlagForm = preload(FlagForm) //drop the props arg

const FlagsApp = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route path="/report/:reportId/flag/:id/edit"
            component={<PreloadedFlagForm {...props} />} //spread it in here instead
        />
    );
};
```

And so the code for `preload` becomes:

```js
export default function preload(WrappedComponent) {
    class Preload extends React.Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            getDataForComponent(this.props);
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
    }
    return Preload;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If like me you didn't read the instructions, the answer lies in the `render` prop of the `<Route>` component

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

> **render: func**
>
> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.

So, instead of passing the wrapper function into the `component` prop, you must use the `render` prop. However, you can't pass in a wrapped component like I did above. I still don't completely understand what's going on, but to ensure params are passed down correctly, this was my solution.

My Preload wrapper function is now a React component that renders a Route...

```
export default class PreloadRoute extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        preload: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        data: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
        location: PropTypes.shape({
            pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        }),
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.preload(this.props.data);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps({ location = {}, preload, data }) {
        const { location: prevLocation = {} } = this.props;

        if (prevLocation.pathname !== location.pathname) {
            preload(data);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Route {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}
```

And then I use it like so...

```
const FlagsApp = (props) => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <PreloadRoute exact path="/report/:reportId/flag/new" preload={showNewFlagForm} data={props} render={() => <FlagForm />} />
            <PreloadRoute exact path="/report/:reportId/flag/:id" preload={showFlag} data={props} render={() => <ViewFlag />} />
            <PreloadRoute path="/report/:reportId/flag/:id/edit" preload={showEditFlagForm} data={props} render={() => <FlagForm />} />
        </Switch>
    );
};
```

The reason I'm calling `this.props.preload` both in `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` is because I then had the opposite issue of the `PreloadRoute` component not remounting when navigating, so this solves that.

Hopefully this save lots of people lots of time, as I've literally spent days getting this working just right. That's the cost of being bleeding edge I guess!